# Set polling interval on EventHub triggered Azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

When using Storage Queue triggered functions, we could set polling interval with `maxPollingInterval` as in host.json [[1]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-output?tabs=csharp#host-json). But when using EventHub triggered functions, I cannot see any option to set the polling interval in hosts.json [[2]](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/host.json). Question: *Is there an option to set polling interval for EventHub triggered functions?*

References: As per this comment [[3]](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/711#issuecomment-371990086) in Azure-Functions Github repostiory, scale controller polls on 10 second interval. As per this link [[4]](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/integrations-on-azure/pull-events-from-event-hub-from-logic-app/ba-p/1588280), it appears logic apps has polling interval for polling from EventHubs.

Comment: Azure Event Hubs provides push based model so there is no polling interval or such on the receivers.

Comment: @SerkantKaraca I was hoping setting `maxPollingInterval` to less than 10 seconds, will cause scale controller to check for new messages in EventHub at that frequency. That assumption was wrong. Closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no way to set the `maxPollingInterval` for Eventhub triggered azure function.

From the source code of `queue trigger`, you can see it defines `maxPollingInterval` [there](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/c2cf82dde5a539f06f632f4f644705256af4c1ba/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage/Queues/Config/QueuesOptions.cs#L95), like below:

```
public TimeSpan MaxPollingInterval{xxx}
```

But for [eventhub trigger](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-eventhubs-extension/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs/Config/EventHubOptions.cs), there is no such definition. You can submit a request there and ask them to add such feature.

BTW, all available settings for eventhub triggered function are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs-trigger?tabs=csharp#functions-2x-and-higher).

Answer (score 2):

With the understanding that EventHubs are push-based, I had raised this query under *wrong* impression that a setting like `maxPollingInterval`, when set to less than 10 seconds, will cause a dead consumption plan function to check for new messages in EventHub at that frequency. This is left here if anyone thinks in the same wrong manner :)

Even for storage queue triggers, the `maxPollingInterval` is of a consequence only when the function is alive. Once the function is stopped (unloaded from memory), even if we had `maxPollingInterval` set to 1 second, that function will be triggered only when scale controller checks storage queue, which happens at its own pace, which *appears* to be 10 seconds currently. The above is applicable only to the consumption plan. When on App service/premium plans, the function is always alive and polling happens as per `maxPollingInterval`.

An alive Eventhub triggered function is waiting for the push-based message and so does not have to poll. So a setting like `maxPollingInterval` makes no sense for event hub triggers.